# What is the data structure used to store your inodes?

Tags: filesystems, inode

As I understand it each file has an inode that holds the data block location and some metadata about that file. What is the method in which these inodes are stored and referenced too? I'm not asking about the inode structure itself but how we differentiate each by its inode number. Do we have a new structure of an inode table kind of like a bitmap? an array of say inodes[0] would make sense to access the inode number of zero.

or I think I am miss understanding. In our file system we store an Inode into the first blocks of memory so say our first block of memory is inode1 and to access the second inode you reach the second block of memory by point to the start of memory plus the size of a block of memory

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is a possible disk layout for a simple file system. The boot block contains special data used to start the entire system. The superblock contains information describing the file system.After the superblock, there may be a section of memory dedicated to a bitmap that tracks how unused blocks in the system. After the bitmap, there is the inode section.

You could have an inode table that is an array of inode structs that would do the translation of inode number to inode for you. It would be as easy as inode_table[0].

Alternatively, and this is how I learned it in my systems class, if you have functions to read and write sectors from physical disk and you know which sector for which the inode section starts and the size of a sector and the size of an inode in bytes, using a bit of arithmetic and modulus operations you can easily fetch the specific inode from the filesystem without the use of an inode table.